# What method do you use to initialize member variables?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class `Foo`, with a member variable that is a `std::vector` of floats, `bar`. I then create an instance of `Foo`, called `foo`. Let's say that I do not know the length of `bar` before the program runs, but at the point when `foo`'s constructor is called, I know that it's length should be `x`.

There are three ways I can think of to initialize the length of `bar`, and I'm just wondering which of the three most people tend to use. I have ranked them in order of what I would consider to be "best practice", but I'm more curious about what method people "actually" use in practice. Sometimes I use methods which make the code clearer to follow, rather than necessarily following best practice...

1. `bar` is a private member, and I resize it during `foo's` constructor, e.g. `Foo foo(x){bar.resize(x)};`
2. `bar` is a private member, and I call `foo.ResizeBar(x)` which resizes `bar` internally, after creating `foo`.
3. `bar` is a public member, and I call `foo.bar.resize(x)`, after creating `foo`.

Or, in code:

1.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    std::vector<float> bar;
public:
    Foo(int x)
    {
        bar.resize(x);
    };
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo(100);
    return 0;
}
```

2.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    std::vector<float> bar;
public:
    Foo()
    {
    };
    void ResizeBar(int x)
    {
        bar.resize(x);
    };
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.ResizeBar(100);
    return 0;
}
```

3.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    std::vector<float> bar;
    Foo()
    {
    };
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar.resize(100);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing your code, why can't you just show it?

Comment: By the way, you *do* know about [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)? If not then you might want to read about them.

Comment: There is no best practice here. You would choose which method to use based on your needs. And since the class name "Foo" is not useful in describing the purpose of this class, any advice here is just a guess.

Comment: agreed, why not do `std::vector( size_t count);` in the initializer list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with all three of your methods is that you're needlessly invoking the default initializer for your vector, and *then* modifying the already initialized vector to suit your needs.

You should be invoking the correct initializer using the initializer list:

```
Foo::Foo(std::size_t x) : bar(x, 0) { }
```

Answer (score 6):

The best method is not in the list of options you posted. The best method is to initialize `bar` using [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

```
Foo::Foo(int x) : bar(x) {}
```